# is this bug? Browser doesn't show jquery show()

Tags: html, jquery

I have city (il) - county (ilçe) - district (semt) selectors.

1. Province "Istanbul"
2. When I select the county as "Esenyurt", jquery works. First, it closes all the districts (semt) with hide() and then opens some of them according to their properties. But the browser doesn't show it. What could be the reason for this?
   The error is exactly as in the fiddle:
   https://jsfiddle.net/mu95yjvL/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#ilce option").hide();
   // $("#semt option").hide();
   $("#il").change(function() {
     var il_id = $(this).val();
     $("#ilce option").hide();
     $("#ilce option[data-il='" + il_id + "']").show();
   });
   $("#ilce").change(function() {
     var ilce_id = $(this).val();
     $("#semt option").hide();
     $("#semt option[data-ilce='" + ilce_id + "']").show();
   });
 });
```

[image]

Comment: I will recommend you put the cities in an object and add it's related counties and districts. Then dynamically add the options `onchange` instead of showing/hiding options.

Comment: Note that the `style='display:none'` in the *markup* is only used when the page first loads - as soon as you do `$("#semt option").hide()` all of those style elements are updated (to display:none)